# How do I represent nested fors in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a construct like the one below, how can I use 1 (or more) list comprehensions to get the same output??

```
f2remove = []
for path in (a,b):
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path,item)):
            x = parse_name(item)
            if x and (ref - x).days >= 0:
                f2remove.append(os.path.join(path,item))
```

I've tried multiple things like

```
files = [parse_name(item)\
         for item in os.listdir(path) \
         for path in (a,b)\
         if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path,item))] # get name error
f2remove = [] # problem, don't have path...
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\karuna\Desktop\test.py", line 33, in <module>
    for item in os.listdir(path) \
NameError: name 'path' is not defined
```

Comment: Shouldn't your if statement be tabbed in?  Also what is your syntax error?

Comment: Your comment says you're getting `syntax` error, while the traceback shows `NameError`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary My bad...  was looking at a different script... (:P to me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of `for`s doesn't change. The condition in your case becomes awkward:

```
f2remove = [
    os.path.join(path, item)
    for path in (a,b)
        for item in os.listdir(path)
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, item))
               for x in (parse_name(item),)
                  if x and (ref - x).days >= 0
   ]
```

basically, to convert nested `for`s to a list comprehension, you just move whatever you were `append`ing to the front:

```
result = []
for a in A:
    for b in B:
      if test(a, b):
         result.append((a, b))
```

becomes

```
result = [
    (a, b)
    for a in A
    for b in B
    if test(a, b)
]
```

Comment: Is there any way of not calling `parse_name()` twice, it is a very slow function..

Comment: @Schoolboy -  Yes. `... if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, item)) for x in (parse_name(item),) if x and (ref-x).days >= 0]`

Comment: @Robᵩ Consider posting it as an answer I'll up-vote it (I'm going to accept this answer though)

Comment: Nah, My answer would be too derivative. @Pavel can incorporate what I said into his answer, though, if he cares to.

Comment: @Robᵩ When does an upvote get locked?? ( out of the thing that killed the cat (curiosity) )

Comment: Added the third trick-loop, it's probably best to stick with regular loops at this point.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job,

```
f2remove = [
       os.path.join(path,item) 
            for item in [os.listdir(path)
                for path in (a,b)] 
                     if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path,item)) 
                           and parse_name(item) and 
                                 (ref - parse_name(item)).days >= 0]
```

but your initial version is really more readable.